# Find curvature and torsion of a curve at one point.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\alpha$ denote the intersection of two surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$.

$S_1$: the surface $z = x^2 -y^2$.

$S_2$: the surface $x^2 + y^2 +z^2 =1$.

I want to find the curvature and torsion of $\alpha$ at the point $p=(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2}, 0)$.

**What I did**: Let $\alpha(s) = (u(s), v(s), u^2(s) - v^2(s))$ with $\alpha(0) = p$. Then $\alpha$ lies on the surface $S_1$. If we assume $u^2 +v^2 + (u^2-v^2)^2=1$ and $u'^2 + v'^2 + (2uu'-2vv')^2=1$, then $\alpha$ also lies on the surface $S_2$. Moreover, $\alpha$ is a unit speed curve.

Then $$\alpha'(s) = (u' , v', 2uu' - 2vv')$$
$$\alpha''(s) = (u'',v'',2u'^2 + 2uu'' - 2v'^2 - 2vv'')$$
$$\kappa = |\alpha''(s)| = \sqrt{u''^2 + v''^2 + (2u'^2 +  2uu'' - 2v'^2 - 2vv'')^2}.$$

To obtain $\kappa (0)$, we need to find information of $u(0),u'(0),u''(0),v(0),v'(0),v''(0)$.
$$u^2 + v^2 + (u^2 - v^2 )^2 = 1 \Rightarrow 2u u' + 2vv' + 2(u^2-v^2)(2uu'-2vv')=0.$$
At $s=0$, we plug $u=1/\sqrt{2}$ and $v= 1/\sqrt{2}$. Then we get
$$\sqrt{2}u'(0) + \sqrt{2}v'(0) + 0 = 0 \Rightarrow u'(0)=-v'(0).$$
Moreover, it follows from  $u'^2 + v'^2 + (2uu'-2vv')^2=1$ and $u'(0)=-v'(0)$, we have

$$ 1= u'^2 + v'^2 + (\sqrt{2}u'-\sqrt{2}v')^2 = 2(u'(0))^2 + 8(u'(0))^2 = 10 (u'(0))^2 .$$
Thus $(u'(0))^2=(v'(0))^2 =1/10$ and $u'(0)v'(0)=-(u'(0))^2 =-1/10$.

Like this (more computation), I can find $u(0),u'(0),u''(0),v(0),v'(0),v''(0)$ and so find $\kappa(0)$. **However, I think this computations are very messy and so I was wondering if there is another simple way to find a curvature at the given point.**

Comment: It is always good to have an idea of the geometrical object you will find. See for that, for example https://www.geogebra.org/m/MxPVbAee

Comment: See as well https://thatsmaths.com/2014/05/29/the-high-power-hypar/

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ \small S1: x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1, S2: z = x^2 - y^2$

There are multiple ways one can parametrize the intersection curve. I will try and use one that I believe is somewhat easier than others.

From $ \small S2, x^2 = y^2 + z$ and plugging it into equation of $ \small S1$,

$ \small \displaystyle y^2 + z + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \implies 2y^2 + (z + \frac{1}{2})^2 = \frac{5}{4}$

Rewriting, $ \displaystyle  \small \frac{y^2}{5/8} + \frac{(z + \frac{1}{2})^2}{5/4} = 1$

So we parametrize the curve in first octant as,

$ \small \displaystyle y = \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}} \cos t, z = - \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}} \sin t$, $x = \sqrt{y^2+z} = \sqrt{\frac{5}{8} \cos^2 t + \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}} \sin t - \frac{1}{2}} $

The given point is $ \small P = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0) \implies \cos t = \frac{2}{\sqrt5}, \sin t = \frac{1}{\sqrt5}$

$ \displaystyle \small r'(t) = \bigg(\frac{- \frac{5}{4} \cos t \sin t + \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}} \cos t }{2 \sqrt{\frac{5}{8} \cos^2 t + \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}} \sin t - \frac{1}{2}}}, - \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}} \sin t, \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}} \cos t \bigg)$

$ \displaystyle \small r''(t) = \bigg(\frac{- \frac{5}{4} \cos 2t - \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}} \sin t }{2 \sqrt{\frac{5}{8} \cos^2 t + \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}} \sin t - \frac{1}{2}}} - \frac{(- \frac{5}{4} \cos t \sin t + \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}} \cos t)^2 }{4 (\frac{5}{8} \cos^2 t + \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}} \sin t - \frac{1}{2})^{3/2}}, - \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}} \cos t, -\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}} \sin t \bigg)$

At point $ \displaystyle \small P, \cos t = \frac{2}{\sqrt5}, \sin t = \frac{1}{\sqrt5}$ so plug in the values to find $ \small r'(t)$ and $ \small r''(t)$ at point $ \small P$.

Then finally evaluate $ \displaystyle \small k = \frac{||r'(t) \times r''(t)||}{||r'(t)||^3} $